# Java Word Count

Tags: java

I am just starting out in Java so I appreciate your patience. Anyways, I am writing a word count program as you can tell by the title, I am stuck at the `numWords` function below the for loop, I am not sure what I should set it equal to. If someone could set me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thank you. Here is all of my code thus far, let me know if I not specific enough in what I am asking, this is my first post. Thanks again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class  WCount {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] wordArray = new String [10000];
        int [] wordCount = new int [10000];
        int numWords = 0;

        while(stdin.hasNextLine()){
            String s = stdin.nextLine();
            String [] words = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s\
+");
            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                numWords = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about your issue. **I am stuck at the numWords function below the for loop, I am not sure what I should set it equal to?!!!!** what does it mean?

Comment: Why are you applying a regex to `s`? Also, why are you assigning `numWords` to `0` in a loop?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, I am confused on what I need to do after the `for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){`

Comment: You aren't incrementing your numwords variable, which is what I'm guessing you are trying to do. Try replacing numwords=0 with numwords++, or just do what sprinter suggested in his answer, which is much better

Answer (score 3):

If your code is intended to just count words, then you don't need to iterate through the `words` array at all. In other words, replace your `for` loop with just:

```
numWords += words.length;
```

Most likely a simpler approach would be to look for sequences of alpha characters:

```
Matcher wordMatch = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(); 
while (wordMatch.find())
    numWords++;
```

If you need to do something with the words (such as store them in a map to a count) then this approach will make that simpler:

```
Map<String,Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
Matcher wordMatch = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(); 

while (wordMatch.find()) {
    String word = wordMatch.group();
    int count = wordCount.getOrDefault(word, 0);
    wordCount.put(word, count + 1);
}
```

Comment: Unless not every string resulting from the split operation is considered to be a "*word*". Then you do not need loop with conditional counting.

Comment: I am trying to write a program that counts the words in a text via stdin, then prints the output in alphabetical order with the word count next to the word. I am just on the beginning phase of the program and for now and trying to just get it to count words correctly. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @PM77-1 OP's code removes all punctuation and non-spaces before doing the split. I'm assuming that means everything left is a word.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. We were all beginners once.

First of all, you don't need to do the loop because "length" attribute already has it. But, if you want to practice with loops is so easy as increasing the counter each time the iterator advances and that's it.

```
numWords++;
```

Comment: how you gonna recognize blank spaces?

Comment: The split() function recognizes the pattern that you want, splits and instantiates for each separate item in the array in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Read the input

```
String sentence = stdin.nextLine();
```

Split the string

```
String [] words = sentence.split(" ");
```

Number of words in a sentence

```
System.out.println("number of words in a sentence are " + words.length);
```

You mentioned in comments that you would also like to print the line in alphabetical order. For that Java got you covered:

```
Arrays.sort(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to count the amount of words in a String `String phrase` is simply to get a String array from it using the String method *split* `String[] words = phrase.split(" ")` and giving it as argument the space itself, this will return a String array with each different words, then you can simple check its length`words.length` and this will give you the exact number.